# The Bletchley Circle, Blood on Their Hands, Part 2: explain ending

Tags: plot-explanation, the-bletchley-circle

At the end of 'Blood on Their Hands, Part 2', in the second season of *The Bletchley Circle*, I'm confused as to why Susan's explanation was not obvious previously.

> At the end of the episode, Susan tells the colonel in the hospital that the injured men at the hospital were deliberately experimented on by Masters. The colonel seems to realize that Oliver Masters has been a loose cannon and calls to send people to Master's house, saving the other members of the Circle. But wouldn't Masters' deception have been obvious to anyone who interviewed the injured men, such as the colonel himself? And was Masters controlling the agents who murdered Richards, shadowing the Circle, etc.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dan,
Although I have looked for some follow-up commentary to corroborate this claim, sadly, this show has little following in the way of discussion. Perhaps you'll be able to accept the claims of a fellow (former) Bletchley Circle watcher.
As you suspect, the plot is very thin. The second season did unravel, as compared to the first. This may be why the scenario is so far fetched, and hinged on the cover up by the secrete military group and silence of the affected soldiers. The one soldier was only too eager to speak to Susan. Probably, Susan's clandestine trip into the hospital wing housing the soldiers was the only outside visitors the soldiers received - weren't the listed as dead from a "crash" or quarantined? Once the hospital realized Susan infiltrated its wing, she was brought to the Colonel, where presumable she would be shamed into confessing to her husband. Susan was much to strong to be ashamed, and came clean with her husband thus convincing the Colonel that there was malpheasance amiss. The Colonel probably had no reason to step on the toes of other senior military men, as was the case at the time.

Comment: "thin plot" - I think that may be the best explanation, as opposed to something I missed.